# codeigniter embedded web page

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering what is the best way to have a web page inside another page in code igniter. From the old code i'm redesigning they use iframes.  Is this the best way to do it?  I want to click on a button on the existing webpage, after it will do some query's and update a corresponding iframe below.

Thanks,

Tariq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ok to do in code igniter or any other web framework for that matter. This is more of an html question than it is a backend question. Happy Coding!